# NPM attempts to publish twice

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I am maintaining my first **npm** package so this might be an error on my part. Once build my package and commit it to **git** the next step is:

```
$ npm version patch
$ npm publish
```

The output (abridged) is as follows:

```
npm notice 
npm notice   @mememe/p3-model@0.7.2
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 188B  README.md                
npm notice 4.5kB dist/doc.d.ts

  (etc) 
            
npm notice 792B  package.json             
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @mememe/p3-model                       
npm notice version:       0.7.2                                   
npm notice filename:      @mememe/p3-model-0.7.2.tgz             
npm notice package size:  6.2 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 23.2 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        cb5588ee626efc21532845c608fdb05a5fcd4db3
npm notice integrity:     sha512-s7IK2HSXCNTUk[...]ZHxDgAOIr4Cnw==
npm notice total files:   11                                      
npm notice 
npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/
⸨⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠇ : notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

So far so good.  But then somehow it attempts to publish *again* and gets an error that I am publishing on top of an old version.  The output continues:

```
> @mememe/p3-model@0.7.2 publish
> npm publish

npm notice ⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠇ : notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm notice   @mememe/p3-model@0.7.2
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 188B  README.md                
npm notice 4.5kB dist/doc.d.ts            
npm notice 6.5kB dist/doc.js     

  (etc)
             
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @mememe/p3-model                       
npm notice version:       0.7.2                                   
npm notice filename:      @mememe/p3-model-0.7.2.tgz             
npm notice package size:  6.2 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 23.2 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        cb5588ee626efc21532845c608fdb05a5fcd4db3
npm notice integrity:     sha512-s7IK2HSXCNTUk[...]ZHxDgAOIr4Cnw==
npm notice total files:   11                                      
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@mememe%2fp3-model - You cannot publish over the previously published versions: 0.7.2.
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
⸨⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠇ : notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I only entered the `npm publish` command once.  Is there some action of this command (perhaps an option in `package.json`) that would cause this?

The correct package gets published and I can use it in other projects.  But this error is a bit disconcerting.   Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue and just solved it.

My problem was, that i had defined a `script` with `publish` in my `package.json`, so it was fired after/before again.

The idea behind that was to have a hint (like a command list) about the commands i use for building, testing, generating documentation and publishing. But unfortunately then the command was fired twice all the time.

In my case, the package.json looked like this:

```js
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo here could be a build job",
    "test": "jasmine",
    "publish": "npm publish"
}
```

Check your `package.json` for a entry at `scripts` which key is named `publish`. If you have an entry with the key `publish`, then remove this line entirely or use a different key for your script.

Comment: My problem did get mitigated but I didn't know the reason.  I did edits to package.json for different reasons and ended up taking out the script as you suggested.

Comment: I had the same problem this week. Learning to make packages, and had defined `"publish": "npm publish --access=public"`. Removed it, went to this post to answer it, and saw the it was already answered! :)